# algorithm to arrange multiple sql queries by timestamp fields in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to sort the results of 3 seperate queries of different tables by a timestamp field that's on each table.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM chores WHERE Status = 'unchecked' ORDER BY Time DESC";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE Status = 'unchecked' ORDER BY DateTime DESC";
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM gyms WHERE Status = 'unchecked' WHERE Endtime IS NOT
NULL ORDER BY EndTime DESC";
```

So say I have those 3 queries, and I want the data from the row whose timestamp field is the 3rd oldest, compared to all of the other rows in all of the other tables.  Is there an easy way to do this either in a SQL Query or in PHP?  I'm struggling with figuring out the logic for it.

Comment: If this 3 tables with same scheme you can use `UNION`, but if these scheme are different you should sort this records into your php code

Comment: please write sample of data and expected result...

Comment: yeah the scheme is different on each one.  The only thing that's the same is the timestamp.

Comment: You should cast each timestamp field as a constant name, e.g. "MyTimestamp", then once you've run all three queries you can simply sort the result array via the "MyTimestamp" key

Comment: I'll have to combine all 3 arrays right? Not sure how I would compare all the resulting arrays

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you have ran your queries and have three separate **associative arrays** containing all the rows...

```
$array1, $array2, and $array3

$test = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
usort($test, 'sortit');
print_r($test);

function sortit($a, $b){
    /* 
        Note, if the column name for the timestamp is not the same for each table,
        this function must know what element to compare for a proper sort.

        Also, this is assuming that the [timestamp] field is a linux epoch, if it is not, then
        simply do this:

        $a_time = strtotime($a['DateString']);
        $b_time = strtotime($b['TimeString']);
        return $a_time >= $b_time ? 1 : -1;
    */
    return $a['timestamp'] >= $b['timestamp'] ? 1 : -1;
}
```